# Cannot marshall type class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue without a custom marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have been building the Android version of my app after creating the iOS version, and I am using AWS DynamoDB for my database.  I have a list item, and am trying to save a nested object within it.  Here is what the document looks like in the database:

[image]

Since I know these are Map datatypes (This is what they are when I load them into the app as well), I attempt to save them as a Map datatype as well.  Here is the code in my FriendsDO AWS Table:

```
public class FriendsDO {
    private String _userFriendsId;
    private List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> _friendRequests;

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "userFriendsId")
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "userFriendsId")
        public String getUserFriendsId() {
            return _userFriendsId;
        }

        public void setUserFriendsId(final String _userFriendsId) {
        this._userFriendsId = _userFriendsId;
        }


        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "friendRequests")
        public List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> getFriendRequests() {
            return _friendRequests;
        }
        public void setFriendRequests(final List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> _friendRequests) {
            this._friendRequests = _friendRequests;
    }
```

I took out the rest of my items to make this more readable.  The following lines of code is what I write when trying to save a new Map item into the List.

```
    FriendsDO friendsTblToUpdate = new FriendsDO();

    List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> requestList = new ArrayList<Map<String, AttributeValue>>();

        Map<String, AttributeValue> mapToSave = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
                            mapToSave.put("friendID", new AttributeValue().withS(personId));
                            mapToSave.put("friendName", new AttributeValue().withS(personName));
                            mapToSave.put("friendUsername", new AttributeValue().withS(personUsername));

                            requestList.add(mapToSave);

            friendTblToUpdate.setUserFriendsId(item.get("userFriendsId").getS());
            friendTblToUpdate.setUserId(fbId);
            friendTblToUpdate.setFriendRequests(requestList);

    try {
       objectMapper.save(friendTblToUpdate);

        } catch (final AmazonClientException ex) {
             ex.printTraceStack();
        }
```

Here is the stack that I receive:

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: Cannot marshall type class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue without a custom marshaler or @DynamoDBDocument annotation.
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getObjectToMapMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:387)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.augment(ConversionSchemas.java:317)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getMemberMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:300)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getMapToMapMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:369)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.augment(ConversionSchemas.java:314)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getMemberMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:300)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getListToListMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:341)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.augment(ConversionSchemas.java:310)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.getMarshaller(ConversionSchemas.java:291)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.ConversionSchemas$StandardItemConverter.convert(ConversionSchemas.java:257)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1044)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
                                                                        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:688)
                                                                        at     com.treyherman.gifwrap.FindFBFriendsActivity$ViewHolder$2$1.run(FindFBFriendsActivity.java:362)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to save a Map item in Android DynamoDB? It was so simple in iOS, I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure it out in Android. Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer, I was just way overthinking everything.  I just had to change the friendRequests data type to look like: `private List<Map<String, String>> _friendRequests;` and then I adjusted the rest of my code accordingly.